# Haskell multiple actions within pattern match

Tags: haskell

For a game I want to use animations, for that I want to pick a picture from a list, and then go to the next picture. However, for that I would need to do two things within one function which is not possible I think.

```
getPicture :: [IO Picture] -> Int -> IO Picture
getPicture a i | i < length a = (!!) i a && getPicture a (i+1)
               | otherwise    = (!!) i a && getPicture a (0)
```

Obviously I cannot use `&&` to proceed to the next part, but I was wondering if there was a possibility to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `(!!) i a` bit is supposed to do, but as long as the two different bits have the same return value, you can absolutely do two things, using a do block

Comment: the (!!) i a is pick element i from list a.

Comment: Well of course you can take an element from a, but what are you doing with it? Are you wanting to output the picture, bind it to a variable? You can use let or where to bind variables.

Comment: Why not just `listofpictures !! i`?

Comment: yes i could also do that, but that is not the main concern here

Comment: Would this help you `[doSomethingWithPicture picture | picture <- listOfPictures]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the next picture"?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're always recursively calling `getPicture`, it looks to me like you just want all the pictures in order. You also have a base case which goes back to the first picture. Don't you think `getPictures :: [IO Picture] -> IO [Picture]` looks like a more suitable signature? It would just get all pictures in a sequence, no need to manually keep track of `i`.

Luckily there's `sequence` from `Control.Monad` which can do exactly this for you. We'll throw in a `cycle` which accommodates the "go back to the beginning" part.

```
do
  pictures <- cycle <$> sequence getPictures
  … -- animate the pictures as you wish
```

Of course I'm just guessing what you might actually want. For example, this will keep all the pictures (frames?) loaded in memory.

Comment: I wanted to constantly switch pictures to mimic animation